# Performance Issue in drawing huge graph with sharpdx

Tags: c#, graph, directx, sharpdx

My task is to draw a huge graph with more than 500,000 nodes and edges, with functionalities such as moving nodes, selecting them, removing and etc.
I am using C# .Net 4.6 winform applicatoin.
I am using sharpdx(directx wrapper for .net), But i have performance issue, each render loop takes 750ms ~ 1.3 fps and that is not acceptable! Also my GPU load is less than 10% , so its seems i am not using my gpu entirely. I am using Direct2D, and i call Draw methods for each node and edge(which i think, this is the main problem!).
My question is how can i do this task with reasonable performance?
or how can i reduce the draw calls. something like batch draw?

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.Windows;
namespace SharpD2D
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Geometry> lstGeoms;
        public Factory Factory2D { get; private set; }
        public SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory FactoryDWrite { get; private set; }
        public RenderTarget RenderTarget2D { get; private set; }
        public RenderControl renderControl { get; private set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitRendererControl(this.Size);
        InitDirect2DAndDirectWrite();
        lstGeoms = Generator.GeomGenerator.getGeoms(Factory2D);
    }

    private void InitRendererControl(System.Drawing.Size? renderSize = null)
    {
        // create instance
        renderControl = new RenderControl();
        //  renderControl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

        if (renderSize.HasValue)
            renderControl.Size = renderControl.ClientSize = renderSize.Value;

        //events
        renderControl.Paint += renderControl_Paint;

        this.Controls.Add(renderControl);
    }

    private void renderControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        renderBoard();

    }

    private void InitDirect2DAndDirectWrite()
    {
        Factory2D = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory(FactoryType.MultiThreaded);
        FactoryDWrite = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory(SharpDX.DirectWrite.FactoryType.Shared);


        var properties = new HwndRenderTargetProperties();
        properties.Hwnd = renderControl.Handle;

        properties.PixelSize = new Size2(renderControl.ClientSize.Width, renderControl.ClientSize.Height);
        properties.PresentOptions = PresentOptions.RetainContents;

        RenderTarget2D = new WindowRenderTarget(Factory2D, new RenderTargetProperties(new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(SharpDX.DXGI.Format.Unknown, AlphaMode.Premultiplied)), properties);
        RenderTarget2D.AntialiasMode = AntialiasMode.Aliased;
        RenderTarget2D.TextAntialiasMode = TextAntialiasMode.Aliased;
    }

    private void renderBoard()
    {
        RenderTarget2D.AntialiasMode = AntialiasMode.Aliased;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        var brush = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.SolidColorBrush(RenderTarget2D, new Color4(0.3f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 1f));

        RenderLoop.Run(renderControl, () =>
        {
            sw.Restart();

            RenderTarget2D.BeginDraw();
            RenderTarget2D.Clear(new Color4(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f));
            foreach (var item in lstGeoms)
            {
                RenderTarget2D.FillGeometry(item, brush);
            }
            RenderTarget2D.Flush();
            RenderTarget2D.EndDraw();
            sw.Stop();
            var totalElappsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var fps = 1000 / (totalElappsed == 0 ? 0.000001 : totalElappsed);
            Console.WriteLine($"Count: {lstGeoms.Count} : {totalElappsed.ToString()} , {fps}");

        });
    }
}
}
```

And the GeomGenerator class wich generates 500k random ellipses:

```
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Generator
{
    public class GeomGenerator
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Vertex
        {
            public Vector4 Position;
            public SharpDX.ColorBGRA Color;
        }
        public static List<Geometry> getGeoms(SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory d2dFactory)
        {
            var lstGeoms = new List<Geometry>();
            int count = 500 * 1000;
            Random r = new Random();
            var bound = 650;
            var lowerBound = 0;
            var upperBound = bound;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var location = new Point(r.Next(lowerBound, upperBound), r.Next(lowerBound, upperBound));
                var center = new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawVector2() { X = location.X, Y = location.Y };
                var ellipse = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Ellipse(center, 1, 1);
                var mainGeo = new EllipseGeometry(d2dFactory, ellipse);
                lstGeoms.Add(mainGeo);

            }
            return lstGeoms;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to cache what has to be rendered. Render into bitmap and use that bitmap instead any further rendering. Re-render only if something changes.

Comment: @Sinatr i cant cache data , because user can drag and move nodes and etc, so while moving a node, it should render a lot to show the process of moving a node. if each render takes 750ms and 10 render needs to move 200pixles its take 7.5 sec to just move a node 200px farther!!!

Comment: Do not re-render the whole geometry when user start dragging something. You can show (render) something on top of bitmap (without changing bitmap, so it's only few lines of rendering). Similar to when you disable showing content of window during resize, you will only see a rectangle during resize, content is rendered only when you finish resizing. Just an idea. Another one is this: most of time is taken by drawing pixels, so you can simplify your geometry (kind of  mipmapping?), e.g. remove invisible (hidden or just too small parts) yourself, then rendering should occurs faster.

Comment: Is using SharpDX with DirectX11 instead of Direct2D an option?

Comment: as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372260(v=vs.85).aspx), try to use more specific drawprimitive calls like DrawRectangle over generic DrawGeometry calls. This is because with DrawRectangle, the geometry is already known so rendering is faster.